# Problems with fetching react.js/node.js

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass some datas from frontend to backend.
Here the code lines....

FRONTEND

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
        alert('A form was submitted: ' + this.state);
 
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/store-data', {
            method: 'POST',
            /*mode: 'cors',*/
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            // We convert the React state to JSON and send it as the POST body
            body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
        
          }).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response)
            return response.json();
          });
          console.log("Sono entrato");
        event.preventDefault();
    }
```

BACKEND

```
app.post("/store-data", (req, res) => {
  let data = { name: req.body.username };
  console.log(data.name);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
  res.json("Hello");
});
```

All the console.log works well.
But if I go on the "localhost:5000/store-data", I get this error:
"CANNOT GET /store-data/ PAGE NOT FOUND 404"
Thanks

I add tis code and now seems to work:

```
app.get("/store-data", (req, res) => {
  let data = { name: req.body.username };
  console.log(data.name);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
  res.send("Hello");
});
```

But I have to keep both the app.get() and the app.post() to work.
I think that is not the correct way.
Thanks

Comment: `store-data` is a POST request. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: In some code in Internet I see that they are able to show text with post.

Comment: When you hit a URL with a browser it's always a GET request, so you'll need a GET route in your backend. Now, if you  want to test your POST route, you can use a REST client like postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it. The problem was that i make a mistake with the fetch method and I get undefined in the return response.json.
Now in the post method res.send work.

It was an error on the Frontend code not in the Backend.
In my case I don't need anymore app.get(....), but only the app.post(.....).